# Count and date statistics in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to write query for MongoDB to create expiration statistics.

- For any existing combination **tenantId**, **orgId**, **status** = 'AVAILABLE' and **uploadTime** between M-N (e.g. 20-30) **days back** from actual date I would like to get statistics which **count numbers of records**
  reaching the last day (N, e.g. 30).
- When there is no record for some day, it will omit it (don't print "logsCount": 0).
- Older the log is the lower "**expireInDays**" value is printed (30 days old = "expireInDays": 1, 20 days old - "expireInDays": 10 ).

Thank you.

**Source data** looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : JUUID("1149194f-695f-47a7-b924-49eba4d8451c"),
    "status" : "AVAILABLE",
    "tenantId" : JUUID("ff1239bd-b405-47b0-b86b-6b77f26ae321"),
    "orgId" : JUUID("0005ae66-fa51-4242-a9d3-e4b39d8256a7"),
    "uploadTime" : ISODate("2021-04-06T18:06:34.130Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : JUUID("297fe229-daee-4bd4-a4c0-cd7a35ba4c2f"),
    "status" : "AVAILABLE",
    "tenantId" : JUUID("ff1239bd-b405-47b0-b86b-6b77f26ae321"),
    "orgId" : JUUID("0005ae66-fa51-4242-a9d3-e4b39d8256a7"),
    "uploadTime" : ISODate("2020-04-05T18:08:42.728Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : JUUID("297fe229-daee-4bd4-a4c0-cd7a35ba4ccc"),
    "status" : "AVAILABLE",
    "tenantId" : JUUID("ff1239bd-b405-47b0-b86b-6b77f26ae321"),
    "orgId" : JUUID("0005ae66-fa51-4242-a9d3-e4b39d8256a7"),
    "uploadTime" : ISODate("2020-03-27T16:08:42.728Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : JUUID("297fe229-daee-4bd4-a4c0-cd7a35ba4ddd"),
    "status" : "AVAILABLE",
    "tenantId" : JUUID("ff1239bd-b405-47b0-b86b-6b77f26ae321"),
    "orgId" : JUUID("0005ae66-fa51-4242-a9d3-e4b39d8256a7"),
    "uploadTime" : ISODate("2020-03-27T16:09:42.728Z"),
}
..
..
.
```

**Result** should look like this one:

```
[
{
    "tenantId": "ff1239bd-b405-47b0-b86b-6b77f26ae321",
    "orgId": "0005ae66-fa51-4242-a9d3-e4b39d8256a7",
    "expirations": [
      {
        "expireInDays": 1,
        "logsCount": 2
      },
      {
        "expireInDays": 9,
        "logsCount": 1
      },
      {
        "expireInDays": 10,
        "logsCount": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "tenantId": "anotherTenant",
    "orgId": "anotherOrg",
    "expirations": [
      {
        "expireInDays": 1,
        "logsCount": 2
      },
      {
        "expireInDays": 2,
        "logsCount": 1
      },
      {
        "expireInDays": 5,
        "logsCount": 1
      },
      {
        "expireInDays": 10,
        "logsCount": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

Little draft (incomplete) is here:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/-iQNa6-JZmh

Comment: I suggest include your draft query within the post (it is generally encouraged so for other''s convenience)..If you know exactly what is the issue you are facing explain that too.